# PHP Get an option value without submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I am working on a website and i want to ask how can i get an option value without submitting the form? I am using MySQL to get the options IDs and Values from the database. (Because its more dynamic than just code it)

```
<form>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
    <select name="Category" id="Category">
            <option value="1">All Category</option>';
    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
    echo "No Result";
    }
    else
    {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            { 
                echo'
                <option value='.$row["KategoriaID"].'>'.$row["KategoriaNEV"].'</option>
                ';
            }
    }
echo'
    </select>
    </li>

    <li>
    <select name="Subcategory">
        <option value="1">Subcategory</option>';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM subkategoriak WHERE KategoriaID = ".$CategoryID."";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);     
    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
    {
    echo "No Result";
    }
    else
    {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            { 
                echo'
                <option value='.$row["SubkategoriaID"].'>'.$row["SubkategoriaNEV"].'</option>
                ';
            }
    }       


    echo'   
    </select>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</form>
```

This is how my code looks like.

Thank you.

Comment: You can't. Not using PHP, at least. What, exactly, are you trying to do, since you want to get an option-value?

Comment: What are you doing with the "value"? The PHP all lives on the server so you can't do it with that.

Comment: Use javascript, look for onchange on #Category, use ajax to send the result to some php code to determine what the subcategories are then pass it back through the ajax call to the javascript to dynamically build/alter the subcategory drop-down.

Comment: I have a select box with name Categorys.
Its like "Motherboards","Hard Drives" etc-etc. The category ID's and names are written in a MySQL database. I can see the options.
Next to this there is a Sub-Category box. I want like if i select "Motherboards" to appear like "AM3+, FM2" etc in the SubCategory menu.

Comment: I've never used ajax or javascript, can anyone write me an example for my code please?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys anyways!
I have found a working system and edited it to mine.

Source: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html